Телеграм бот не подключается к серверу
Столкнулся я с такой проблемой, пишу бота на java, бот не может подключиться к серверу, хотя проект запускается без каких любо проблем и к базе данных подключение есть, но бот никак не подключается. В качестве сервера я использую timeweb
Вот мой application.yaml:
bot:
  name: name_bot
  token: token
  path: https://IPv4:8443

server:
  port: 8080

И вот ссылка, которую я использовал для настройки telegram bot api:
https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook?url=https://IPv4:8443
Контроллер
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebhookController {
 
    private final WebhookBot bot;
 
    @PostMapping("/")
    public BotApiMethod<?> onUpdateReceived(@RequestBody Update update) {
        return bot.onWebhookUpdateReceived(update);
    }
}


Вы пытаетесь подключить бота к серверу на локальном компьютере?

Нет, я пытаюсь подключиться к облочному серверу на timeweb

Он там нормально развернулся? Пробовали пингануть?

Вроде как нормально. Все сервисы и контроллер создаются, подключается к бд, но никак не принимает updates от телеграма

попробуйте залогировать и проинвестигировать, что вообще происходит. Также попробуйте послать post запрос на этот endpoint через curl или postman и посмотреть что отвечает ваш сервер.

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED IPv4:8443

IPv4 это вы скрываете реальный ip от нас или так и пишите?

Это я скрываю реальный ip

ок, ну ECONNREFUSED означает что даже приконектиться не получилось, видимо никто не отвечает на этом порту

а server.port = 8080 может вам туда нужно обращаться?

"Вроде как нормально." - т.е. вы не пинговали, а просто по логам посмотрели что сервер развернулся?

Telegram bot api работает только на портах 8443, 443, 80 и 88

Да, я его не пинговал

Попробуйте curl запрос на IPv4:8080

Error: write EPROTO 37244552:error:1000000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

это https запрос?

Ну по крайней мере ответил, ну вот в общем и проблема, вы запускаете сервер на 8080, а боту говорите 8443. Открытый вопрос по поводу SSL так понимаю будет.

Я так понимаю, мне нужно преобрести SSL сертификат?

Ну для начала надо поменять 8080 на 8443. Далее: 443 и 8443 обычно указывают на HTTPS, 80 и 88 в теории могут обычный HTTP предоставлять, но надо посмотреть, можно ли боту дать ссылку на http без https. Если да, то попробуйте поменять порт на 88 в обоих местах (и серверу, и боту указать). Если не получится, то да, скорее всего потребуется SSL, но там не всё так просто. Можно выпустить бесплатный через letsencrypt. Там больше проблем с установкой этого сертификата на сервер.

Благодарю за ответ
